# How can I spread the paths in the y axis?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have 14 series of lines. I would like to show them with a spacing between them. something like in the image, I think the best option is with the translate property. I do not know how to do it with each line. I'm trying to get my data between 0 and 100

http://plnkr.co/edit/qmkxYEJYpIkXUQUMQMDa?p=preview

[image]

```
 paths.attr('transform', null)
        .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .ease('linear')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + x(now - (limit - 1) * duration) + ')')
        .each('end', tick)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a scale band (or v3 ordinal scale with rangeBand) to translate the lines, and the scale linear to draw the lines

http://plnkr.co/edit/qs1i4sVzBXl6de7b8HJ3?p=preview

```
 var band = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(ids)
            .rangeBands([height, 0])
```

and

```
for (var name in groups) {
            var group = groups[name];
            let g = paths.append("g")
              .attr("transform", function(d,i){
                return "translate(0, " + band(name) +")";
              });
            group.path = g.append('path')
                .data([group.data])
                .attr('class', name + ' group')
                .style('stroke', group.color)
        }
```

Comment: but agree with Gerardo's post that a" for loop" for this is not best practice

Comment: your solution is better because it (almost) avoids magic numbers (the almost refers to the y range, you could use a `length` to compute that `14`).

Comment: yeah, agree that the y range would be better calculated by other means, or have a set height per line chart, and change the overall svg height depending on the number of lines to be drawn

Comment: @TomShanley great!! great! Many thanks, could you please explain how I can change the height or separation of the series? I want to avoid having to scroll

Comment: Check out the API for range Bands or better still, upgrade to v4 for scaleband as these have controls for spacing etc

Answer (score 1):

Your problem right now is that horrendous `for...in` loop. **Do not** use loops to append elements in a D3 code. It's not only unnecessary but it will also make things very difficult to change, like your situation right now.

Thus, since you have that loop (I'll not refactor the code to eliminate that, it's simply too much work for a — free — S.O. answer), this is my solution:

First, increase the height of the chart and decrease the range of the `y` scale. Here, I'm setting the height to `800` and the range to `[45, 0]`. Change that accordingly (or, if you want to avoid magic numbers — always a good idea — have a look at the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46677671/5768908))

Then, in the for loop, translate each element according to a counter, here named `index`:

```
var index = 0;

for (var name in groups) {
    var group = groups[name]
    group.path = paths.append('path')
        .data([group.data])
        .attr('class', name + ' group')
        .style('stroke', group.color)
        .attr("transform", function() {
            return "translate(0," + (55 * index++) + ")";
        })
}
```

This is your plunker with those changes: http://plnkr.co/edit/NPhWMpcorXhAubwytmOe?p=preview

Comment: Hi Gerardo maybe can you help me with this please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46823073/how-can-i-make-to-display-my-data-more-quickly-on-my-chart

Comment: Hello @yavg. Sorry, but I have a personal rule: I just answer a question if it takes me less than 5ish minutes. That is, for me, the limit that separates a free answer at StackOverflow from a paid work at Upwork.

Comment: I see. What if you make an exception at least for today? I would thank you from the bottom of my heart. No one is able to help me with this and I have a blocker from a long time ago. maybe I would not pay you with money, but believe me that I would be totally grateful and learn a lot, this is something that money can not buy. Give me one last chance please have an exception. yes?

Comment: I'm on my mobile now, when i get to my computer I'll see if I can do anything.

Comment: Thank you!! of course you can if you can not, then no one can. I really appreciate it and I will not get used to it, I promise.

Comment: please do not forget me friend !, obviously when you can.

Comment: As I said your question requires too much work and I'm very busy now. Just set a bounty to it, it will attract more people.

Comment: thanks for answering. how do I do that reward and in what way?