# Using d3.js, how can I display data faster on my chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In my code, I am loading a JSON with 508 entries on a line chart. This JSON contains data emitted by some machines, and the keys are the names of the machines.

This is the structure of my JSON:

```
{
    "AF3":3605.1496928113393,
    "AF4":-6000.4375230516,
    "F3":1700.3827875419374,
    "F4":4822.544985821321,
    "F7":4903.330735023786,
    "F8":824.4048714773611,
    "FC5":3259.4071092472655,
    "FC6":4248.067359141752,
    "O1":3714.5106599153364,
    "O2":697.2904723891061,
    "P7":522.7300768483767,
    "P8":4050.79490288753,
    "T7":2939.896657485737,
    "T8":9.551935316881588
}
```

I am currently reading the data with the help of a counter called `cont`, however, the code that I'm using takes too long to draw the graph:

```
data.length=508

if (data.length>cont)
 cont++`

for (var name in groups) {
  var group = groups[name]
  group.data.push(aData[cont][name])
  group.path.attr('d', line)
  console.log(cont)
}
```

[image]

As you can see in the gif above, my code is taking too long to plot all the data points. I would like to draw all the data elements of my data set (in this case 508) without delay, for example:

```
data=[{508 elements}];
tick(data)=> draw the points in the graph at the same time, by dataset.

data2=[{50 elements}];
tick(data)=> draw the points in the graph at the same time, by dataset.
```

Where `tick` is the name of the function that would draw the coordinates, without losing the sense of animation.

[image]

How can do it?

Here is a link to my code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/y8h9zs1CpLU1BZRoWZi4?p=preview

Comment: console.log might slow things down there.

Comment: @TahaPaksu I have commented the console.log () and it does not make the difference

Comment: Instead of drawing all at once, draw just some parts of your graphs (the visible parts in the browser)

Comment: @John I do not know how to do it. can you help me please?

Comment: When working with data, try to use "console.table()"

Comment: Looking at the code from that link I can see a few problems. Firstly, you are iterating an object which usually takes longer than iterating an array. Secondly, you are defining an anonymous array inside a loop, instead of defining it outside and then plugging it inside the loop. I don't work with svg, I work with canvas, so my only help would be to write the animation with canvas.

Comment: Your current animation pans across a subset of data, while 'masking' any data outside your current range. When you say you wish to plot all your points without delay, does that mean in a single frame you would like to see your full data set (i.e. a typical line chart)? If so, then what do you wish your animation to be of?

Answer (score 6):

It seems to me that your problem is the fact that the graph is synchronous - "duration" is both used for animation and for graph shifting. Essentially, changing duration will avail nothing.

You can introduce a time multiplier. Then try dividing duration by two, and using a multiplier of 2. Your actual data duration is now duration*timeMultiplier (you might want to change the names to make it less confusing, or use a timeDivider in the animation).

```
// Shift domain
x.domain([now - (limit - 2) * duration * timeMultiplier, now - duration * timeMultiplier])

// Slide x-axis left
axis.transition()
  .duration(duration)
  .ease('linear')
  .call(x.axis);

// Slide paths left
var t = paths.attr('transform', null)
  .transition()
  .duration(duration)
  .ease('linear')
t.attr('transform', 'translate(' + x(now - (limit - 1) * duration * timeMultiplier) + ')')
  .each('end', tick)
```

Another thing you might try is to add the points two at a time, i.e. you skip the shift on odd ticks, and shift *double the amount* on even ticks. This reduces the overhead at the expense of making the animation a bit jaggier (but not very much, because it also plays faster).

Comment: @yavg I would STRONGLY suggest not ransoming your votes like this. If this helped you, vote on this one. Don't vote on this one based on what L.Serni does on your OTHER question.

Comment: @yavg, totally agree with Patrice. In case, just notify me of the other question and I'll see whether I can help you. **DO NOT** accept (or even upvote) an answer if *that answer is not useful*, otherwise the next poor guy with this problem will believe something works, when it actually doesn't. And he'll probably take it out on *me*! ;-D. That said, I *will* look at that other question later tonight.

Comment: @LSerni   friends are absolutely right. but I do not know if it makes me understand, but what happens is that this question one way or another I have found the solution, and then my next problem is the new question I have asked. if someone helped me with the other question, one way or another it would be resolved.